# Pick which value to feed in second parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have a report with two date: `ProductCreatedDate, ProductSoldDate`. User need to be able to filter either on `createdDate` or `SoldDate` not both. How can I do this?
I am thinking of creating three parameters. First one will give user an option to select which date they want to filter on. For example:

```
First Parameter-
Pick Date type:
Product Created Date
Product Sold Date
Second parameter based on first parameter value-
Start Date (calendar form)
Third parameter based on first parameter value-
End Date (Calendar form)
```

Let's say user selects value `Product Created Date` as a first parameter

Then second and third (start and end date calendar) parameter should be based on `ProductCreatedDate` filter

Any suggestion, on how to do this?

What I have tried hoping it will work:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN @Type = 'Created' THEN ProductCreatedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate END)
OR (CASE WHEN @Type = 'Sold' THEN ProductSoldDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate END)
```

Comment: please give it an earnest try first. What I see here is "hey yall I want to do XYZ please give me it" rather than ""hey yall I tried XYZ and it gives bugs here whats going on?"

Comment: ..so the suggestion is to show us your code (or screenshots.. or somethiing) ; - )

Comment: I have tried adding a case statement in my where clause so the parameters are depending on the previous parameter but that doesn't work so I have no clue on how to do it. I have also searched around for an answer and couldn't find anything on what I am looking for. To be honest I am not even sure if it is possible and I am not asking for "give it to me the code" I asked for suggestions or ideas on how to approach it. I promise you I like challenging myself but I am kind of stuck on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have 3 parameters (DateType, StartDate, EndDate) you can just add some ANDS and ORS in your WHERE.

```
WHERE (@DateType = 'Created' AND ProductCreatedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
      OR (@DateType = 'Sold' AND ProductSoldDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

Comment: DateType isn't a field, it is only a parameter I want to create to allow users to pick. Based on the picked value, second and third parameter will feed its value. What I am trying: Please see my post for code